# Read Web Service Response and Write to Excel in Groovy Script (using SOAP)

Tags: excel, web-services, soap, groovy

I have written below code to read values dynamically from Excel, call web service from SOAP UI and to write values between Response tags to Excel.

```
import jxl.*; 
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException; 
import jxl.write.*; 

def reqOperationName = "TestRequest"; 
def inputDataFileName = "Automate/SampleData.xls";
def inputDataSheetName = "sendSampleData";
log.info("Service Testing Started")     
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(inputDataFileName)); 
WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(inputDataFileName),workbook); 
    WritableSheet sheetl = copy.getSheet(inputDataSheetName); 

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context); 
def reqholder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(reqOperationName+"#Request");
    try{ 
        rowcount = sheetl.getRows(); 
        colcount = sheetl.getColumns(); 
        for(Row in 1..rowcount-1){
            for(Col in 2..colcount-1){
                String reqTagName = sheetl.getCell(Col,0).getContents() 
                def TagCount = reqholder["count(//*:"+reqTagName+")"] 

                    if(TagCount!=0){
                            String reqTagValue = sheetl.getCell(Col,Row).getContents() 
                            reqholder.setNodeValue("//*:"+reqTagName, reqTagValue) 
                            reqholder.updateProperty() 
                        } 
            } 
                        // To Run Test Request 
                        testRunner.runTestStepByName(reqOperationName) 
        //Read Response XML
                def resholder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(reqOperationName+"#Response")

                resTagValue1 = resholder.getNodeValues("//*:message")

                //Write Response value to Excel Sheet
                Label resValue1 = new Label(8,Row,java.lang.String resTagValue1);
                        sheetl.addCell(resValue1);
        }// Row loop Ends Here 
    }catch (Exception e) {log.info(e) }
        finally{
            copy.write(); 
            copy.close(); 
            workbook.close(); 
        } 
log.info("Service Testing Finished")
```

Response from my web service is as shown follows:-

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soap:Body>
  <Response xmlns="http://eh.dummy.com">
     <sets xmlns="">
        <sets_InnerSet xmlns="http://eh.dummy.com">
           <visibleSetsInnerSet>
              <set_cd>QS1</set_cd>
           </visibleSetsInnerSet>
           <visibleSetsInnerSet>
              <set_cd>QS8</set_cd>
           </visibleSetsInnerSet>
           <visibleSetsInnerSet>
              <set_cd>QS9</set_cd>
           </visibleSetsInnerSet>
        </sets_InnerSet>
     </sets>
     <responseCode xmlns="">success</responseCode>
  </Response>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Can you please let me know how can I read values (QS1/QS8/QS9) from set_CD tags and write to Excel file in a single cell as QS1, QS8, QS9.

Comment: Is the issue writing into excel or extracting the data and creating it into desired format? where is the difficulty that you have? Instead of Image, can you edit the question and paste the response xml ?

Comment: I'm facing issues while extracting data from the required tags of response and creating in desired format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below groovy code snippet to get the desired value in the required format.

```
//Pass the xml string to parseText method below i.e., your response
def parsedXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
//Get the desired value in required format
def result = parsedXml.'**'.findAll {it.name() == 'set_cd'}.collect{it.text().trim()}.join(',')
log.info "Desired output : $result"

//You can use result variable to write or use anywhere you needed
```

You can try this quickly online <kbd>[Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5182877562044416)</kbd>

Hoping that you will be able to proceed and write the above retried `result` to where you needed.